# Stacked and grouped column in time series

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to have grouped columns displayed in a time series. So for every timeframe there will be 2 columns with stacked data.

The problem is that this would be 3 dimensional data and I have no idea if Highcharts can handle this. Also how would the xAxis handle the display of date and column name?

The only thing that I came up with is this: http://jsfiddle.net/7p34o3w5/1/

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      pointInterval: 86400000,
      pointStart: 1411336800000
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "Politik",
    stack: 0,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Panorama",
    stack: 0,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Kultur",
    stack: 0,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Wirtschaft",
    stack: 0,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Politik",
    stack: 1,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Panorama",
    stack: 1,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Kultur",
    stack: 1,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }, {
    "name": "Wirtschaft",
    stack: 1,
    "data": [100, 100]
  }]
}
```

Comment: You need to setup xaxis type as datetime, and use i.e3 stacks, or define x values for each serie. Then you achieve 3 stacks. Is it possible to attach a mockup how it should look like?

Comment: Ok switched to `datetime`. But my main problem is that it creates a new color for every item on a different stack. The goal is that item `Wirtschaft` for example has the same color on every stack and only show up ones in the legend. Also update the question so the number of stacks matches the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showInLegend` parmater and set it as false, on "second" serie of the same name. Then use `linkedTo` param.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7p34o3w5/1/

Comment: Updated the example but it still use different colors: http://jsfiddle.net/7p34o3w5/2/

Comment: The only solution for the color problem I found is to set it explicit for every series.